# Postgresql ORDER with GROUP BY and millions of rows

Tags: postgresql

i am using this query:

```
SELECT ttt.id_tour_term, tt.id_tour, tt.min FROM (
 SELECT id_tour, MIN(pricefrom) AS min, date_start
 FROM tours_terms 
 WHERE pricefrom > 500
 GROUP BY id_tour, date_start
 ORDER BY min
 ) tt INNER JOIN tours_terms ttt ON tt.id_tour = ttt.id_tour 
 AND tt.min = ttt.pricefrom AND tt.date_start = ttt.date_start
 LIMIT 10;
```

this is SQL create:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."tours_terms" ( 
"id" BIGINT DEFAULT nextval('tours_terms_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
"id_tour_term" BIGINT, 
......
"id_tour" BIGINT NOT NULL, 
......
"date_start" Date NOT NULL, 
......
"pricefrom" BIGINT NOT NULL, 
......
PRIMARY KEY ( "id" )
);

CREATE INDEX "index123" ON "public"."tours_terms" USING btree( "id_tour" ASC NULLS LAST, "date_start" ASC NULLS LAST, "pricefrom" ASC NULLS LAST );
```

EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
Limit (cost=223761.30..552651.91 rows=10 width=24) (actual    time=17221.437..17221.576 rows=10 loops=1)
   -> Merge Join (cost=223761.30..782875.35 rows=17 width=24) (actual    time=17221.435..17221.568 rows=10 loops=1)
   Merge Cond: ((ttt.id_tour = tours_terms.id_tour) AND (ttt.date_start = tours_terms.date_start) AND (ttt.pricefrom = (min(tours_terms.pricefrom))))
-> Index Scan using index123 on tours_terms ttt (cost=0.43..535445.38 rows=2798151 width=28) (actual time=0.026..0.120 rows=10 loops=1)
-> Sort (cost=223760.87..224431.57 rows=268280 width=20) (actual time=17221.382..17221.388 rows=10 loops=1)
Sort Key: tours_terms.id_tour, tours_terms.date_start, (min(tours_terms.pricefrom))
Sort Method: external sort Disk: 46968kB
-> Sort (cost=196217.39..196888.09 rows=268280 width=20) (actual time=10421.422..11989.747 rows=1412964 loops=1)
Sort Key: (min(tours_terms.pricefrom))
Sort Method: external merge Disk: 41424kB
-> GroupAggregate (cost=0.43..172027.42 rows=268280 width=20) (actual time=0.035..4988.960 rows=1412964 loops=1)
-> Index Only Scan using index123 on tours_terms (cost=0.43..149223.67 rows=2682793 width=20) (actual time=0.026..2322.927 rows=2701457 loops=1)
Index Cond: (pricefrom > 500)
Heap Fetches: 441882
Total runtime: 17290.012 ms
```

Version is 9.3.6

Can pls anybody help me optimize this query?

Problem is, that i have table with millions of rows, where "id_tour", "priceform" and "date_start" is duplicated, so i must do this group by stuff.

Comment: `where "id_tour", "priceform" and "date_start" is duplicated, ` why is it duplicated ?

Comment: Table have informations about terms from tours. 1 tour have n terms.
I must search over terms, because they have all params like date_start, pricefrom, etd.
So: 
- id_tour is relation to tours
- date_start maybe duplicate too
- priceform will be of course duplicate

Comment: @Maniac why would `priceform` be duplicate of course? Aren't there multiple records for each tour's term that only differ with price?

Comment: Oh, and you should start with setting `WORK_MEM` to higher value, 50MB should be a good start.

Comment: @JakubKania I set it to 100MB and still same result

Comment: @JakubKania because they are sometimes duplicate. Only "date_start" is different in this case. I have some duplicates, but this is probably my mistake.

Comment: Why do you have an ORDER BY in the subquery? Does it change the query plan? And what about even more work_mem? Try 200MB, 500MB or even 1GB.

Comment: @FrankHeikens There must be order. You want terms ordered by MIN price. Its like Eshop. Sorted products by parameter.

Comment: @Maniac: Why don't you order in the outer query? To me it looks like it only matters in the end result, not in the subquery: The subquery returns everything.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I tried to incrase WORK_MEM to 1GB and try to order in outer query. Same results. But now, it took 21 seconds.

Comment: @FrankHeikens but interesting is this:

`SELECT id_tour, MIN(pricefrom) AS min, date_start
 FROM tours_terms 
 WHERE pricefrom > 500
 GROUP BY id_tour, date_start
 ORDER BY min`

It took 17 ms.